# How to treat global errors without displaying the error ribbon in spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am doing the following call to execute an action only in case an user exists

```
    private _userConnector: UserConnector,
    ....
    this._userConnector.get(userId).subscribe(() => {
         // conditional action
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log('your handling goes here');
    });
```

However, if the `userId` does not exist the error ribbon appears on the back:
[image]

I dived deep in all the method calls behind `_userConnector.get` but I did not find how to only catch the error in susbscribe avoiding the red error ribbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error handling is implemented in low level http interceptors. There's a documentation that [describes the handlers and how to customise them](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/http-error-handling/).

The error that you notice in the message box is likely driven by the `ForbiddenHandler`, which is configured to handle 403 errors. You can customise the handler to avoid the error in the message box. See the [implementation on github](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/21d3b6cfd2f0c5921507879ebdaa14ea8804a472/projects/core/src/global-message/http-interceptors/handlers/forbidden/forbidden.handler.ts#L13).